# Console says function I created does not exist

Tags: javascript, function, console, runtime-error

When I run this code:

```js
//Function to see if a line is colliding with a certain point Has an accuracy of about 1 pixel
    this.lineIsColliding = function(startX, startY, endX, endY, testX, testY) {
        const v1 = {
            x: endX - startX,
            y: endY - startY
        };
        const l2 = v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y;
        if (l2 === 0) {
            return false;
        } // line has no length so can't be near anything
        const v2 = {
            x: testX - startX,
            y: testY - startY
        };
        const u = (v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y) / l2;
        return u >= 0 && u <= 1 && Math.abs((v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x) / Math.sqrt(l2)) < 1;
    };

    //The Canvas to draw on
    this.src = src;
    //The context of source(used for drawing)
    this.ctx = this.src.getContext("2d");
    //The Mouse Move Function
    this.showCoordinates = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        label.innerHTML = "<b>x: </b>" + e.offsetX + " <b>y: </b>" + e.offsetY + ", " + this.lineIsColliding(358, 277, 365, 268, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    };
```

(not whole code. Snipped to only show important parts)

the console says that my lineIsColliding function does not exist! Here is exactly what it says:
Uncaught TypeError: this.lineIsColliding is not a function

Comment: guess it depends on how you are calling `lineIsColliding` - because clearly your `this` is not what you think it is (`this` can be confusing)

Comment: ahh, `showCoordinates` handles an event - that's why `this` is not what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your **this** is referring to the **this** inside the small function scope. Use var self = this; in the upper scope.

Then invoke the function again like this:

`self.lineIsColliding(358, 277, 365, 268, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);`